# Why isn't my code working? I'm not sure why it's saying 'row' is not defined

Tags: python

My code is here:

```
def pe():
  print("This program will output a parallelogram.")
 
def rows():
  row = int(input("How long do you want each side to be?"))
  return(row)
 
def de():
  character = input("Please enter the character you want it to be made of:")
 
def make_shape():
  for i in range(row):
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        print(character, end="")
    print()
 
    for k in range(1, row + 1):
      for l in range(1, row + 1):
        if(l < k):
            print(' ', end = "")
        else:
            print(character, end = "")
    print()
 
def main():
  pe()
  rows()
  de()
  make_shape()
 
main()
```

Any ideas to why python is saying `row` is not defined? Is it not globalized or something, I'm honestly so confused.

Comment: you return row in `rows()` but dont forward it to `make_shape()` where you want to use it. save rows to a variable `my_rows = rows()` and use is as parameter `make_shape(my_rows)`. same for `character`

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, you also have to forward character from function de so that it will be known by function make_shape.

Comment: @DarrylG I tried this but now it says name 'character' is not defined

Comment: @JonathanWong--as Tim Roberts answer illustrates you have to forward both of these parameters i.e. rows and characters to make_shape.

Answer (score 1):

It is BECAUSE they are not globalized that they aren't defined.  The best way is to pass them as parameters:

```
def de():
  return input("Please enter the character you want it to be made of:")
...
def make_shape(row, character):
   ...
def main():
  pe()
  row = rows()
  char = de()
  make_shape(row, char)
```

It's a bit silly to define a function for a single line like this.